# Ubuntu is refusing to boot. 2 partitions and can't access the drive via Live-USB or CD

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I have dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. When I tried to boot Ubuntu earlier today, it was working fine. I turned it off and tried to turn it back on, it showed that purple screen then followed by a black one. I don't know what to do. Anyone can help?

Comment: Give more details. Partitions? Is Windows working? Can you access your drive using a Live-CD or Live-USB? Consider editing the question title to  be more precise (so it can be helpful to people with a similar problem).

Comment: Sorry. 2 partitions, one for windows and the other for ubuntu (250 GB each). No I can't access my drive using CD's or USB's. It's dual boot and I installed both OS's myself. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the version I'm using.

Comment: Is your system able to boot into BIOS/UEFI? If yes have you checked the boot sequence? Have you tried booting without any USB devices attached. Please add the details to your question not to the comments.

Comment: BIOS should still let you boot Ubuntu on USB flash drive. You may have to change BIOS settings to allow USB boot. May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Just a second... I can go into the BIOS screen and I can attach a USB. I went into recovery mode and it opened the terminal. Does this help?

Comment: I got my old USB from my friend which I first installed ubuntu on. Can I like repair it from there?